# Executing Linux sort command and using self defined temporary directory

Tags: linux, shell, sorting, cron, permission-denied

I am working on a project, where in I need to sort some files. I have workflows which are executed as jobs, scheduled once or twice a week. But the main problem is when I execute the same sort command from my own host, it doesnt give any error.

The command which I execute from my own host:

```
sort -k2,2 -T=${TMP_DIR} $1 > $2
On runtime all the **$ variables** are given path provided as arguments.
```

But when I execute on a production host through the job scheduler, it gives following error:

```
sort: cannot create temporary file in `=': No such file or directory
```

2. When I execute the command:

   sort -k2,2 -T ${TMP_DIR} $1 > $2

   The execution is **just stuck** at this step on my own host as well as production host.
3. FYI: this command without "=" works good here in another script of same package: The command used here is:

   ```
   join \<(sort -u -k1 -T ${TMP_DIR} ${INPUT_FILE_1}) \<(sort -u -k1 -T ${TMP_DIR}  ${INPUT_FILE_2}) \> ${OUTPUT_FILE}";
   ```

Is it something related to **-ka,a and -ka** options?

4. I also tried using **--temporary-directory=** option in the sort command, then it works on my local machine, but when I execute it through job scheduler on the production host, it gives permission denied error.

The job scheduler is executing the job as a system account (runas user is some system account).

I have ensured that the copying directory and the directory to which it is getting created are **chowned** to this **system account**

Also the file which is being sorted has **777 permissions**
And the temp directory is getting created through code itself, so the system account is ofcourse its owner!!

Why are such strange things happening?

I am more curious about the **-T option** of the sort command and its solution, and y its behaving so strangely.

Comment: are your devl system and prod system different variants of unix/linux? I guess in any case, check `man sort` on both and see what ithey say about `-T` . I don't recall every seeing an `=` being allowed for `-T`, but things change. Permission denied is a separate issue. Did look at permissions fo parent dirs on the production -T target? Good luck.

Comment: for point (2): TMP_DIR is probably not defined, so sort it is not stuck, just waiting for standard input after having setup $1 as temporary directoryò about (3), I doubt -T will work with = on any system. About (4): it means in that case it works, and you got a different permissions error.